# Can't select item in UICollectionView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to set a default item when the view is loaded this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   self.collectionView.delegate = self
   self.collectionView.dataSource = self
   self.collectionView.allowsSelection = true
   self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

}
```

I'm trying to select an item in the `viewDidAppear` method:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.bottom)
    })
}
```

But the `didSelectItemAt` method is not fired like I need.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
   //some config
}
```

Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 25):

`didSelectItemAt` is not called if you call `selectItem` programmatically. You should call the method manually after it.

```
self.collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
self.collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
```

Comment: Calling `self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])` might be better because off-screen cells will probably crash your app. It depends on the logic of your cells, though

Answer (score 20):

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618057-selectitem) of `selectItem(at:animated:scrollPosition:)`

> This method does not cause any selection-related delegate methods to be called.

That means you will have to call the delegate method manually.

Answer (score 13):

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .left)
}
```

This is the solution which is working for me. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

self.activityCollectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0), at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.right, animated: true)

}

//viewDidAppear is the key
```

Answer (score 3):

For my case, I need to combine Tamàs and iDev750's answer:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
    self.collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
}
```

Comment: When I call it without `DipatchQueue.main.async`, `didSelectItemAt` function called but `collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)` return nil.

Answer (score 0):

None of above answer worked with me because cell in `IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)` in my `collectionView` isn't visible so my app crashed. Than i fixed it with scrolling to [0,0] and waiting until `collectionView` finishes its animation then selected item with calling delegate method `didSelectItemAt` manually. Now it works perfectly.

Example Code:

```
/** scroll to cell that you want to select it */
layoutsCollectionView.selectItem(at: .init(item: 0, section: 0),
                                         animated: true,
                                         scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)

/** implement UIScrollViewDelegate in your view controller and call */
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    /** 
     * here scroll animation finished thats mean your cell is visible
     * now you can select your cell with delegate method
     */
    layoutsCollectionView.delegate?.collectionView?(self.layoutsCollectionView, didSelectItemAt: [0,0])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All other answer since this post don't state which view controller method to place the collection view select methods. Try placing it within the viewDidAppear method.